# Express and (possibly simplify) Logical expressions as a tree

Tags: tree, logic, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics, boolean-expression

I've been given a bunch of boolean expressions(in a sum of products form) like these for example:

```
(1  & 0  &  2) |
(1  & 0  &  3  &  4  &  5) |
(1  &  6  &  7  &  2  &  8) |
(1  &  6 &  3) |
(6  &  7  &  8) |
(1  &  9  &  11  &  12 &  10) |
(1  &  9  &  11  &  12  &  13)
```

Each number (eg: 1, 0 etc) represents an atomic boolean expression.

1. I'd like to lay them out in a single condition tree.
   (For ex:

   ```
   1
      0
         2
         3
            4
              5
    ...
   ```

I would like to lay them out in a tree like above (ie every branch represents a condition expression and every node represents an atomic condition).

When I lay them out in a tree, I also need to cater to the following.

1. The tree must not have conflicting conditions (ie every branch should be mutually exclusive). The tree building algorithm must make a best possible effort to ensure that the branches are constructed without conflicts (although I'm not sure if it can be done 100% because the input conditions may be conflicting by itself).
2. A few conditions are repeated and have multiple parents (eg: '8' it has 2 different parents 2 and 7_ - this violates the principles of a tree.

I'm trying to find any pointers to the approach that needs to be taken to solve this problem.
Also interested to validate my sentiments that problem cannot be solved 100% (meaning, we cannot get a conflict-free tree) as this depends on the nature of the input conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my script is what you want. I make a little script using php, html, css and a css library call Treeflex (flexbox based CSS library for drawing hierarchy trees with HTML lists) to draw a tree from your boolean expression.

I assume logical OR operator (|) separated branches.

In branch (1  &  6 &  3) you can see 4  &  5 nodes at the end because in other branch three is "father" of four, I am not sure if it is right or not.

Input data:

```
$booleanExpression = "(1  & 0  &  2) | (1  & 0  &  3  &  4  &  5) | (1  &  6  &  7  &  2  &  8) | (1  &  6 &  3) | (6  &  7  &  8) | (1  &  9  &  11  &  12 &  10) | (1  &  9  &  11  &  12  &  13)";
```

Functions:

```
<?php

const ROOT_NODE = "Root";

**
 * Function to parse boolean Expression into an
 * associative array with each node and its father.
 * Duplicate nodes (some node number and father) are
 * not included.
 * 
 * @param string $booleanExpression
 * @return array("node", "father", "order", "branchNumber")
 */
function parseExpression($booleanExpression) {
    $nodes = [];

    $branchs = explode("|", $booleanExpression);
    $branchNumber = 1;

    foreach($branchs as $branch) {
        $branchClear = preg_replace("(\(|\))", "", $branch);

        $branchNodes = array_map(function($n) {
                                    return trim($n);
                                }, explode("&", trim($branchClear)));

        $order = 1;
        $nodeFather = ROOT_NODE;

        foreach($branchNodes as $node) {
            $key = array_search($node, array_column($nodes, "node"));

            if($key === false || array_column($nodes, "father")[$key] !== $nodeFather) {
                $nodes[] = array("node" => $node, "father" => $nodeFather, "order" => $order, "branchNumber" => $branchNumber);
            }

            $order++;
            $nodeFather = $node;
        }

        $branchNumber++;
    }

    //Order could be omit:

    usort($nodes, function($a, $b) {
        if($a["order"] == $b["order"]) {
            if($a["father"] == $b["father"]) {
                if($a["branchNumber"] <= $b["branchNumber"]) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if($a["father"] < $b["father"]) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if($a["order"] < $b["order"]) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });

    return $nodes;
}

/**
 * Functión to draw the html tree;
 * 
 * @param array("node", "father", "order", "branchNumber") $nodes
 * @param exp $father
 * @return string //html code
 */
function getTree($nodes, $father) {
    $res = "";
    $res .= "<li>";
    $res .= "<span class='tf-nc'>{$father}</span>";
    $cantHijos = 0;

    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        if($node['father'] == $father) {
            $cantHijos++;

            $res .= $cantHijos == 1 ? "<ul>" : "";

            $res .= getTree($nodes, $node["node"]);
        }
    }

    $res .= $cantHijos > 0 ? "</ul>" : "";

    $res .= "</li>";

    return $res;
}

?>
```

Code:

```
<?php

$tree = getTree(parseExpression($booleanExpression), ROOT_NODE);

echo "<div class='tf-tree'>";
echo "<ul>";

echo $tree;

echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";

?>
```

The output is the html code below:

```css
/*
MIT License

Copyright (c) 2018 dumptyd

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
*/

.tf-tree {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto
}

.tf-tree * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.tf-tree ul {
  display: inline-flex
}

.tf-tree li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative
}

.tf-tree li ul {
  margin: 2em 0
}

.tf-tree li li:before {
  border-top: .0625em solid #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: .0625em;
  left: -.03125em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.03125em;
  width: 100%
}

.tf-tree li li:first-child:before {
  left: calc(50% - .03125em);
  max-width: calc(50% + .0625em)
}

.tf-tree li li:last-child:before {
  left: auto;
  max-width: calc(50% + .0625em);
  right: calc(50% - .03125em)
}

.tf-tree li li:only-child:before {
  display: none
}

.tf-tree li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before {
  height: 1.0625em;
  top: -1.0625em
}

.tf-tree .tf-nc,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content {
  border: .0625em solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  position: relative
}

.tf-tree .tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content:before {
  top: -1.03125em
}

.tf-tree .tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree .tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content:after,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content:before {
  border-left: .0625em solid #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  left: calc(50% - .03125em);
  position: absolute;
  width: .0625em
}

.tf-tree .tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content:after {
  top: calc(100% + .03125em)
}

.tf-tree .tf-nc:only-child:after,
.tf-tree .tf-node-content:only-child:after,
.tf-tree>ul>li>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree>ul>li>.tf-node-content:before {
  display: none
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li {
  padding: 0 .6em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-node-content:before {
  height: .6em;
  top: -.6em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-node-content:after {
  height: .6em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li ul {
  margin: 1.2em 0
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:before {
  top: -.63125em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before {
  height: .6625em;
  top: -.6625em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li {
  padding: 0 1.5em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-node-content:before {
  height: 1.5em;
  top: -1.5em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-node-content:after {
  height: 1.5em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li ul {
  margin: 3em 0
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:before {
  top: -1.53125em
}

.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before {
  height: 1.5625em;
  top: -1.5625em
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-node-content:after,
.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-node-content:before {
  border-left-style: dotted
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children li:before {
  border-top-style: dotted
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children>.tf-node-content:before {
  border-left-style: solid
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-nc:after,
.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-node-content:after,
.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-node-content:before {
  border-left-style: dashed
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children li:before {
  border-top-style: dashed
}

.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children>.tf-nc:before,
.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children>.tf-node-content:before {
  border-left-style: solid
}
```

```html
<div class='tf-tree'>
  <ul>
    <li><span class='tf-nc'>Root</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class='tf-nc'>1</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>0</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>2</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>8</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>3</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>4</span>
                      <ul>
                        <li><span class='tf-nc'>5</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>6</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>7</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>8</span></li>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>2</span>
                      <ul>
                        <li><span class='tf-nc'>8</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>3</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>4</span>
                      <ul>
                        <li><span class='tf-nc'>5</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>9</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>11</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>12</span>
                      <ul>
                        <li><span class='tf-nc'>10</span></li>
                        <li><span class='tf-nc'>13</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class='tf-nc'>6</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>7</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>8</span></li>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>2</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>8</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>3</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>4</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>5</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]